# How to specify location.href with multiple objects of the same class?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Okay, so I have multiple objects of the same name:

```
<a href="<?php echo Utils::createLink('delete-ms'); ?>&tid=<?php echo $tid; ?>"
class="delete-ms">

<img src="img/status/CANCELED.png" alt="" title="Delete milestone." 
class="icon" style="width:18px; height: 18px; margin:0;"/>

</a>
```

Here's the  that the object references:

```
<div id="delete-ms-dialog" title="Delete this milestone?">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;">  
</span>This milestone will be deleted. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

And here's the JS used to call the link:

```
function initDeleteMSDialog() {
var deleteDialog = $('#delete-ms-dialog');
var deleteLink = $('.delete-ms');
deleteDialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 476,
    buttons: {
        'OK': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            location.href = deleteLink.attr('href');
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
deleteLink.click(function() {
    deleteDialog.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

}

Now my problem is that multiple objects are declared with the same class. When the JS function is called, it uses the class as the source of the link. How can I get it so that the location.href references the link that I'm clicking to initiate the dialog box in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try declaring a global variable outside of your function.

```
var $lastClicked;
```

And set the variable when deleteLink.click is triggered.

```
deleteLink.click(function() {
    $lastClicked = $(this);
    deleteDialog.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

This would allow you to have access to the variable within the deleteDialog function.

```
    'OK': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        location.href = $lastClicked.attr('href');
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to loop over all the elements with the same class like

```
$(".delete-ms").each(function(){
 console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hZezC/3/

edit

inside the click event you can access the target anchor's href attr like

```
$(".delete-ms").click(function(e){
 console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: I just want location.href to specify the location of the link clicked. Obviously there is ambiguity in which 'href' attribute is being assigned when there are multiple links of the same class. Will this accomplish that?